# How to use Kolmogorov's law 0 or 1 here?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence, borel-sets, kolmogorov-complexity

Let $f$ be a Borel function of the coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots$ such that for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2},\ldots) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},x_i,x_{i+2},\ldots)$$
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots$ be independent random variables with the same distribution. We want to prove that the random variable $f(X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots)$ is a constant with probability 1.

> The teacher gave me a hint that this must apparently follow from Kolmogorov's law 0 or 1, or nearby facts. But idk how to do this.

Comment: I thought that since we can rearrange and the function will be equal (according to the condition), the function will simply be equal for any rearrangement and therefore it is a constant, but the teacher said that the solution does not work because: "By rearranging one pair of variables we can rearrange any finite number of objects. But no one promises that the property will hold if we rearrange a countable number of objects."

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Comment: @PhoemueX Hewitt-Savage zero-one law tells us about "unchanged by finite permutations" but the teacher said that the proof must work for permutations of a countable number of objects hmmm